# (*variable) and *&variable, what is the difference?

Tags: go, pointers, struct

i am learning GO using exercism.com and reading the recommended documentation and articles from the syllabus.

now i am in struct and found the next code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Employee struct {
  firstName, lastName string
  salary              int
  fullTime            bool
}

func main() {
  employee := &Employee{
    firstName: "Walddys",
    lastName:  "Dorrejo",
    salary:    1200,
    fullTime:  true,
  }
  fmt.Println("firstName", (*employee).firstName)
}
```

but by error, I typed `fmt.Println("firstName", *&employee.firstName)`, which bring me the same result that the previous used in the block of code.

My question is, if exist any different of using this pointer or is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&x` generates a pointer to `x`, while `*p` dereferences the pointer `p`. So effectively `*` and `&` cancel each other out, for example the two statements `v := *&x` and `v := x` are identical.

That means that `*&employee.firstName` is identical to `employee.firstName`.

And where `employee` is a pointer to a struct and `firstName` is a field of that struct, the expression `employee.firstName` is actually a shorthand for `(*employee).firstName`.

This means that `*&employee.firstName` is also identical to `(*employee).firstName`.

---

Note that you should always prefer to use the shorthand notation.

Answer (score 3):

`*&` is redundant syntax - it gets the pointer to the value and then dereferences the pointer - essentially a `NOP`.

If you install static analysis tools like [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/docs/getting-started/) - or use an editor like [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with built in static analysis - you'll get the following warning:

```
*&x will be simplified to x. It will not copy x. (SA4001)
```

https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA4001